# Is there a frequency limitation with timer2 (TIM2) on STM32?

Tags: timer, stm32

I'm working with timer 2 (TIM2) of
[STM32F103](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32-mainstream-mcus/stm32f1-series/stm32f103.html)
to make a clock interrupt set and reset an output pin (PA1) in the interrupt routine of the timer.
So when I set the parameters of timer as below:

```
TIM_BaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = 36;          
TIM_BaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
```

On the logic analyzer, I just saw a clock frequency of only 478 kHz for that output pin instead of the expected 1 Mhz.
When I decreased the TIM_Period, the clock frequency didn't change and remained about 500 Khz.

What is the problem?

```
int main(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    SystemInit();           
    Init_NVIC();                

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA | RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB | RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOE | RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);

    /* PA1 CLK TIM2_CH2 */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 ;               
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;           
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    /* PB0 CK */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 ;               
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;           
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    Init_TIMER();               
    while(1)
    {   
    }     
}
void Init_NVIC(void)
{
    NVIC_InitTypeDef    NVIC_InitStructure;

    #ifdef  VECT_TAB_RAM
      NVIC_SetVectorTable(NVIC_VectTab_RAM, 0x0);           
    #else
      NVIC_SetVectorTable(NVIC_VectTab_FLASH, 0x0);           
    #endif
    NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_0);     

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;         
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;   

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;      
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;         
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);                         
}

void Init_TIMER(void)
{
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef  TIM_BaseInitStructure;         
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef  TIM_OCInitStructure;

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

    TIM_DeInit(TIM2);

    TIM_InternalClockConfig(TIM2); 

    TIM_BaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = 18;

    TIM_BaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;                

    TIM_BaseInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1; 
    TIM_BaseInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;   

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_BaseInitStructure);         

    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_Toggle;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 18;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
    TIM_OC2Init(TIM2, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

    TIM_OC2PreloadConfig(TIM2, TIM_OCPreload_Disable);

    TIM_ClearFlag(TIM2, TIM_IT_CC2);

    TIM_ITConfig(TIM2,TIM_IT_CC2, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);   
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    CK = ~CK;

    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_CC2) != RESET)         
    {
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_CC2);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what "Except 1Mhz" means, and I'm not sure what you decreased TIM_Period to, or what your other configuration code is. Could you provide more details?

Comment: I mean instead of 1MHZ.

Comment: I changed TIM_Period to 18, 36 and 72 and for all of these values the frequency of clock was just about 470KHZ.But for values larger than 72 it worked correct.

Comment: TIMxCLK= SYSCLK/(TIM_Prescaler+1)  and                        Frequency of clock * 2 =(TIM_Period/TIMxCLK)^(-1)

Comment: I think you need to post the rest of your TIM code, because it depends which clk is being used for that particular timer. The clk being used could be the peripheral high-speed, or low-speed etc, and this clk determines what "Period" and "Pre-scaler" mean. Also, your GPIO clk and speed matter as well. Final note: if you are toggling at 1MHz, then your output frequency will be 500KHz (two transitions per period).

Comment: also i added the output in the logic analyzer.Why the CK was not the same as PA1? with those values in the code , PA1 is about 2MHZ and CK is about 490KHZ.

Comment: Sorry, what is CK, and where is it defined? And also, I understand you need a.) A timer, and b.) a GPIO for toggling, based on timer countdown, is that correct? So why do you need two GPIOs?

Comment: CK is PB0 and i defined it in a separate header file . I need 2 GPIOs to work with a ccd sensor (tsl1401) . one of these GPIOs is Clock (5KHZ to 2MHZ)and another one is a pulse that generated each 128 Clocks of CK.

Comment: If interrupt routine didn't work right at high frequencies like 1MHZ i couldn't count clock for 128 times to make second pulse.(second GPIO)

Comment: So How can i count rising edges of clock in Toggle mode?